# Network storage API to retrieve target IPs

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm currently using this SoftLayer API call to retrieve ISCSI target IP.

```
client['Network_Storage'].getNetworkConnectionDetails(id=iscsi_id)
```

However, this calls only return one IP but we need both IPs to configure multi path.

Please advice on the correct API to retrieve both IPs to configure MPIO.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to use the same method, but changing the iscsi_id with the iscsi_id of the replica.

try this:

```
objectMask=mask[serviceResourceBackendIpAddress,replicationPartners[serviceResourceBackendIpAddress],replicatingLuns[serviceResourceBackendIpAddress]]
client['Network_Storage'].getObject(id=iscsi_id,mask=objectMask)
```

that objectMask will return the replica and the IP

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice.  Unfortunately the device I'm using does not return any replicationPartners or replicatingLuns.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I forgot to mention that my ISCSI device is endurance ISCSI.  Not sure if it makes a different.

Comment: using the control portal can you see the replica for your storage?

Comment: Yes, I can see them in two different pages, one on the block storage detail page, and another one from the storage tab of the device that's authorized to use the storage.  However, this is not consistent though, meaning sometimes I see both and other times I see the same IP on both pages.

Comment: Make sure that your API user is the same as the user that you used in the control portal. If that does not fix your issue I recommend you to submmit a ticket to softlayer